# Form submission fails via Ajax due to parsing error, but passes during normal POST

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, jquery

I'm quite puzzled as to why the ajax form submission isn't working. Can you guys have a look and tell me if you can spot something wrong.

WORKING

```
<form id="advancedSearchForm" name="advancedSearchForm" action="" method="POST">
....
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

It's Ajax equivalent for form submission isn't working.

```
<form id="advancedSearchForm" name="advancedSearchForm" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return sumbitForm();">
```

where I have defined the function as

```
function submitForm()
{
$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: '', data: $('#advancedSearchForm').serialize(),dateType:'script',error: alert ("Error in ajax submission"),success: alert ("success")});
}
```

*Update, I just added the alert error function, which does pop up. But so does the success pop up*

In the second one, I am getting a Parsing JSON request failed. In the body, when DOM is loaded, I have a `$.ajaxSetup({error:function(x,e){......if(e == "parsererror") errortext = "Parsing JSON request failed".`

*The controller seems to be sending and receiving the correct data in both instances from the log*. If you have any ideas, pitch in.

Comment: `parseerror` means your server-side script isn't returning content that matches the datatype, which just so happens to be `script` in this case. Also note, you seem to have a typo, `dateType` should be `dataType`

Comment: But the controller is sending exactly the same data in both cases. Should I be sending the returning content in a different format?

Comment: The data being the same has nothing to do with it. The ajax request is succeeding, jQuery just can't process it because the data being returned isn't matching the dataType that you provided for jQuery to expect.

Comment: Is "serilaize" a typo?

Comment: @MikeRobinson - Yes it is. I'm not going to make it that easy for you or me. :-)

Comment: If the code in your question is copied directly from your code, it is full of typos and syntax errors. The way you have your alerts is wrong for starters.

Comment: @KevinB - It isn't. I am using another laptop atm. But still, Really full of typos and syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, the way it is written right now, you will get both the success and error alerts one after the other BEFORE the ajax request is even sent. the `dateType` typo is significant too, if that's actually in your code.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have the success and error before. Just added it a few minutes back, trying to debug it. How should I write it?...I have switched to the correct laptop now, so there will be no typos for sure. It's now purely my ignorance of the rules.

Comment: I'll just give the error example: `error: function(xhr,status,message){ alert('Status: ' + status + ' Message: ' + message); }` the `function(){...}` part can't be left out unless you pass a function reference to it.

Comment: The dataType is correctly written in the code. But the dataType has 'script' has me wondering. On form sumbission I just want to return the control back to the controller, and forget that the call was ever made via AJAX, or a direct post. Should I be having dataType has null instead?

Comment: Making that change should get you an alert that states "*Status: 200 Message: parseerror*" which would indicate a data missmatch. We would then need to see what data you are returning from the act page.

Comment: Just omit the dataType parameter if you don't care what is returned, it will default to text.

Comment: @KevinB - NOPE...Infact I get success :). Still not real success, mind you. The parsing json request failed still shows up in my browser, but success in this ajax call.

Comment: that doesn't make sense.... you can't get both success and then a global error.

Comment: @KevinB - A little update. on dataType 'script' - I don't get success message. On dataType:null - I get success message. But in both cases, I still also get Parsing JSON request failed.

Comment: Beats me Kevin. But I appreciate the help. It's becoming very hard to trace the error.